# Prove that $2\cdot r=l$ for radius r of circle inscribed in a square of length l.

Tags: geometry

The title says it all, however i would like to elaborate the whole problem.

*Problem:*
Consider an equilateral triangle inscribed in a circle. Suppose this circle is inscribed in a square.
Let $A_{c}$, $A_{s}$, $A_{t}$ be area of circle, square and triangle respectively.
Find $A_{t}/A_{s}$?

*Partial Solution:*

By Definition,

$A_{c}=\pi\cdot r^2$,
$A_{s}=l^2$,
$A_{t}=(b \cdot h)/2$
where *r* is the radius of circle, *l* is the length of the side of square, *b* and *h* are base length and height of triangle respectively.

*Intuitive solution (more assumptions):*

Let

1. $r = l/2 $
2. $b = l$
3. $h=l/2$

then $A_{t}/A_{s}= 1/4$

The assumptions are not justifiable but I think they give a hint for approaching the actual solution.

I am not sure about the assumption no. 2 and 3 but the first looks promising for an inscribed circle in a square.

I would appreciate any ideas for proving it.

Comment: The first one is certainly true.  The segment from the center of the circle to a point of tangency is perpendicular to one side, so parallel to another side, and half its length.  (Consider the other radius parallel to that second side.)

Comment: @saulspatz can you give a reference to a proof of this theorem please. It sounds like its straight from the Elements but i would like a more modern solution.

Comment: No, I don't have a reference.  A radius is perpendicular to a tangent at the point of tangency.  That's certainly in the *Elements*, and I would imagine, in any elementary plane geometry book.

Comment: If these answers help you, you should upvote them.  If one of them solved your problem, you should accept it.

Answer (score 1):

The first one is certainly true. The segment from the center of the circle to a point of tangency is perpendicular to one side, so parallel to another side, and half its length. (Consider the other radius parallel to that second side.)

Comment: Ok I've searched through all google and i still don't have any clue what this means..